# Laravel SQS Queue -> delayed jobs fail

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-sqs, laravel-queue

I am trying to delay a job in Laravel that is dispatched to a AWS SQS queue.
Standard jobs that are not delayed run fine on that queue but as soon as I delay something, it crashes. I first tried:

```
$awsgatewayjob = new \App\Jobs\DispatchAwsGatewayJob();
$this->dispatch($awsgatewayjob)->delay(now()->addMinutes(1));
```

This gives error:
*Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_ERROR)
Call to a member function delay() on string*

Next, I tried to do it using the style Laravel explains in the manual:

```
DispatchAwsGatewayJob::dispatch()->delay(now()->addMinutes(1));
```

And this gives error:

*Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_ERROR)
Call to undefined method Maqe\LaravelSqsFifo\SqsFifoQueue::getSeconds()*

I googled the last error and I am happy to report I am not the only one that experienced that error: https://github.com/maqe/laravel-sqs-fifo/issues/7

Anyway, I don't get it. I am running on Laravel 5.5 and I updated all my packages with composer update to make sure I wasn't using an outdated package.

Any ideas?

Here is the (redacted) code for the job:

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;

use Auth;
use Session;

use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;
use Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException;
use Alert;


class DispatchAwsGatewayJob implements ShouldQueue
{

  private $method;
  private $rest_method;
  private $data;

  use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

  /**
  * Create a new job instance.
  *
  * @return void
  */
  public function __construct($method, $rest_method, $data)
  {
    $this->method = $method;
    $this->rest_method = $rest_method;
    $this->data = $data;

  }

  /**
  * Execute the job.
  *
  * @return void
  */
  public function handle()
  {
    $curl = curl_init();
    
    // some more stuff here to config $curl

    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
  }
}
```

Here is the full error log:

Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError thrown with message "Call to undefined method Maqe\LaravelSqsFifo\SqsFifoQueue::getSeconds()"

Stacktrace:

## 0 Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError in /var/www/sparkwebsite/vendor/maqe/laravel-sqs-fifo/src/SqsFifoQueue.php:42

This is the complete stacktrace. I am now using a standard queue and everything runs fine!

Comment: Can you show us how you write your `DispatchAwsGatewayJob`? The first way you did it is wrong, and secondly, `Maqe\LaravelSqsFifo` only calls `getSeconds` when the method is defined ([source code](https://github.com/maqe/laravel-sqs-fifo/blob/master/src/SqsFifoQueue.php#L42-L46)), but weird that you get that error?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Interesting that I always did it wrong, I guess by not supplying a delay it did somehow work? Since I've been dispatching jobs for that quite some time... Anyway, here is the code, I've placed it in the original comment above.

Comment: Ah.... mmm I noticed I have a fifo queue @ Amazon... That might explain things.

Comment: For the `getSeconds()` error, could you also provide the full error log stack? Just want to see how the call chains. By right the fifo library should have checked the method properly but it seems like it failed weirdly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your specific error is because the `getSeconds()` method was removed in Laravel 5.4. That package has an update in the master branch to add 5.4+ compatibility, but there is no tagged release with that code, so you'd have to update your composer.json file to point to `dev-master`.

However, there is a bigger issue at play here. While the package you're using attempts to support the `delay` functionality, this isn't actually correct.

SQS FIFO queues do not support per-message delays. They only support per-queue delays, meaning you must define your queue in AWS with a delay (max 15 minutes), as seen in the screenshot below. Attempting to set a delay on a message sent to a queue that is not defined with a delay will not have any effect.

[image: SQS Settings with Delay Outlined]

So, if you have some jobs that don't use a delay and some jobs that do use a delay, you would need to create at least two queues: one without a delay defined and one with a delay defined. Then, instead of using the `delay()` method, you would have to use the `onQueue()` method to send your job to the queue defined with a delay.

Full disclosure: I have also created a Laravel package for handling SQS FIFO queues ([shiftonelabs/laravel-sqs-fifo-queue](https://github.com/shiftonelabs/laravel-sqs-fifo-queue)). Because of the per-message delay restriction on FIFO queues, my package throws an exception when the attempt is made (`BadMethodCallException('FIFO queues do not support per-message delays.')`), though this behavior can be changed via the package config ([as described here](https://github.com/shiftonelabs/laravel-sqs-fifo-queue#delayed-jobs)).

My package also supports the ability to specify other FIFO specific values, such as the message group id and the deduplication id.

Comment: Wow thanks top comment. I also indeed noticed I used a FIFO queue and fixed that. But your reply goes into much more detail and I'll therefore mark as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of different jobs that need different amounts of delay, it might not be very useful to have 2 versions of each queue.

Another option would be to have a redis or database queue that can easily take delays, which then dispatches the job to SQS.